# Maximum variance of a discrete probability distribution over a set of N fixed numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $P_i$ is a probability distribution over a set $\\{a_i\\}$ i.e. $\\{a_1,a_2,...a_N\\}$ where the $a_i$'s are fixed and $N$ is finite.

If the mean is defined by
$$
\langle a \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{N} P_i a_i
$$

Then what will be the maximum value of the variance $\langle a^2 \rangle - (\langle a \rangle)^2 $?

Note: this is a variation of the post [Maximum variance of a discrete probability distribution over the non-negative integers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329684/maximum-variance-of-a-discrete-probability-distribution-over-the-non-negative-in) Here the set $\\{a_i\\}$ was simply the set of first $N$ non-negative integers, but my question is for a more general finite set.

Any guidance on how to approach this would be helpful!

Comment: This may be of interest: [What is the max variance distribution with fixed mean and support](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455058/what-is-the-max-variance-distribution-with-fixed-mean-and-support).

Comment: Here I am not given the range of the discrete ai's or the maximum/minimum out of the set